# TypeError: to_frame() got an unexpected keyword argument 'index'

Tags: python, pandas

I am referring to [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Index.to_frame.html) documentation page. Here is my code:

`top_sectors = firm['Sectors'].value_counts().to_frame(index = False)`

`firm` is  a dataframe. I need it in Dataframe format for 
Please let me know what I am doing wrong.

Comment: You are calling the [pd.Series.to_frame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html#pandas-series-to-frame).... not pd.Index.to_frame method.  The pd.Series.to_frame method does not have an `index` parameter.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @Scott Boston, `pd.Series.to_frame()` has no `index` parameter. But I needed the index to be separate. So here's a workaround I figured out:

```
top_sectors = firm['Sectors'].value_counts().to_frame()
top_sectors() = top_sectors.reset_index()
```

It adds a new index column and treats the previous index as a column. Here's a screenshot:

[image]

If you want to change the name:

`top_sectors.rename(columns = {'index':'new_name'})`